# How to keep celery crisp?

Tags: storage-method, celery

I like celery, but it seems to go limp very quickly when I buy it.

What's the best way to store it to keep it crisper longer?

Comment: how long would you like it to last?

Comment: @jim as long as possible :)

Comment: no problem, i get it :-) @Joe's answer is the right one

Answer (score 8):

Trim the root end, then set the stalks upright in a tall glass, add a few inches of water, then stash in the fridge.

You'll want to change out the water every couple of days, or can get strange on you.

You can also cut it into shorter lengths, and store it completely submerged in water; this may be necessary to do with part of the stalks anyway, as most people don't have their fridge shelving adjusted to handle the full height of a bunch of celery.

Comment: Wouldn't storing in water will promote the growth of bacteria like  Listeria. Yes I know the fridge is cold, but that just slows, not stops growth

Comment: @TFD : changing the water out is important ... I likely should have specified chlorinated tap water, so there's an anti-bacterial quality to the water.  I've never tried this with ozonated water (which is treated, but doesn't have a long-term anti-microbial properties)

Answer (score 3):

Trim the celery, place on a lightly dampened  paper towel and wrap in aluminum foil. Store in the fridge veggie drawer. Keeps well for at least a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Store in an mostly airtight container, even a basic plastic bag with the opening folded over will do

Feel free to chop a long celery bunch in half. The cut ends do deteriorate a little over time, but not that fast, and it's better than bending or squishing them into the fridge

Just don't let it sit in moving air as exists it most fridges

Answer (score 2):

If you have time, you can do some mason jars with celery. You can act like it is shown in that tutorial: http://www.salad-in-a-jar.com/skinny-secrets/salad-in-a-jar - I know it's about lettuce, but I did analogous thing with celery and it was good. And if you want quick hack, just wrap your celery in aluminium foil: http://www.listonic.com/protips/get/mshkilezox .